# mailchimp multiple welcome email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mailchimp

Is there a method to send a "welcome email" (or a normal mail) everytime that the user update his interests?

I would like to send a different "welcome mail" based on the choose of the user.
in the welcome mail template i used the Conditional (Dynamic) Content in MailChimp (https://blog.mailchimp.com/conditional-dynamic-content-in-mailchimp/) to display different content based on the choose of the user.

but, i don't know if it is possible send more than one "welcome mail".

any idea or advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send emails when interest groups change by using [Automations](http://mailchimp.com/features/automation/). To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible to send multiple "welcome" emails, though.

Comment: thanks, in fact i stopped when I understood that i can't send more the one "welcome email".

do you think that with Automations I can send an email every time that the user update a interest groups?

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems likely. There are workflow types for 'joins interest group' and 'leaves interest group'. See [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/automation/about-workflow-types#subscriber).